# What does 「私が犯人だったとしても？」 imply here?

Tags: meaning

> 甲斐：地検に告発を。
>
> 幸村：その前に本人と話す。
>
> 甲斐：それが正しい対応ですか。
>
> 幸村：弁明の機会を与える。私のやり方よ。
>
> 甲斐：すべきじゃない。
>
> 幸村：私が犯人だったとしても？(pause)
>
> 幸村：上杉先生とは共に戦ってきたの。(end of scene)

Two lawyers are talking about another person suspected of embezzlement in [『スーツ』](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUITS/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%84_(%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%81%AE%E3%83%86%E3%83%AC%E3%83%93%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9E)). For reference, [the entire scene can be found here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3cXVJXqsJU).

私が犯人だったとしても-- even if I were a culprit

But I am not sure what 幸村 means exactly here. I see two possibilities:

1. She is using herself as an unlikely example to rebut 甲斐's すべきじゃない, implying 甲斐 would react quite differently: "Would you also report me, were I ever a culprit?"
2. She is saying: Are you doubting me? Are you suspecting I might be complicit in this?

#2 doesn't seem very likely, because if it is #2, I don't what is omitted after としても.

Comment: One possibility would be "Are you still going to stop me were I ever a culprit?" (i.e. "If you are doubting me, isn't this a good chance for you to find something on me?"), but with this context alone, I may be totally wrong.

Comment: @naruto Thanks. I updated the question to include one more line and I've pretty much transcribed the entire scene... I have also put up a link to the actual scene, for context...

Comment: I’m struggling to understand why you thought #2 might be the case. Is your question more about whether 犯人 refers to a culprit in general (#1) or one, or the one, in this particular case of embezzlement (#2)?

Comment: @aguijonazo My first thought was #1: 幸村 is essentially saying, "You'd give me a second chance, so I should give 上杉 one too." But the subtitles (unofficial translation) gave, "Are you suspecting my involvement?" That's how my possibility #2 came about... Also as you say, whether 犯人 is a general or specific reference also seems vague... I am not sure if she is trying to say, "If I ever did something like this..." or "Are you suspecting I have been involved with 上杉 in the embezzlement?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't watched the show at all so it's possible that I'm totally wrong, but given the background:

- 甲斐 and 幸村 are new partners
- 幸村 and 上杉 were old partners

in other words, 幸村 : 上杉 = 甲斐 : 幸村

And what the previous two lines say, without omission, are:

- （私［幸村］は上杉に）弁明の機会を与える。
- （あなた［幸村］は上杉に）す（=弁明の機会を与える）べきじゃない。

Then this line is possibly intended to be:

> 私［幸村］が犯人だったとしても（あなた［甲斐］は私［幸村］に弁明の機会を与えないのか）？

Answer (score 1):

One possibility I can think of is that she is presenting the hypothesis that she is the sole culprit, in which case Uesugi would not be part of it and therefore deserve a chance to explain himself. She could be asking if he would still stop her from giving Uesugi that chance.

For #1 to be plausible, the two at the scene must be in such a relationship that (she knows that he knows that) he would likely give her such a chance if she were in Uesugi’s shoes. I have never watched the series and don’t know if they are.

But poor acting…

Answer (score 1):

From the text can tell that 甲斐's way of doing thing is "地検に告発を" without informing the culprit before(その前に本人と話さない). But 幸村 thinks culprit should be informed before(その前に本人と話す) to have a chance to explain him/herself(弁明の機会を与える), and this is 幸村's way of doing things(私のやり方よ). 甲斐 don't agree with 幸村's way. So what 幸村 assumes(私が犯人だったとしても？) is: if I were the culprit, will you directly "地検に告発を" without informing me before as well? (I didn't see the scene, but I guess they two are friends or have a close relationship?)

Comment: Here  幸村' s assumption is questioning 甲斐's way of doing things.  Apparently. 幸村 is not agree with that.